# Which ways can be used to log in to Wordpress?

Tags: php, login, htaccess, security

*FYI: This has been also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202955/which-ways-can-be-used-to-log-in-to-wordpress) since I'm fairly new to this website and didn't know that the Wordpress part existed. Sorry for the repost.*

I'm currently trying to tighten the security for a website which is running on [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) (seperate installation, not on wordpress.org / .com). I have installed [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) which blocks all IPs which try to use a invalid user name instantly which works quite well (some 200+ blocked IPs / day).

Since our ISP is giving out hostnames like

```
www-xxx-yyy-zzz.my.isp.tld
```

and there are no users which need log in besides me I thought I would add some way to further prevent brute-force attacks.

The WP Codex has a [section about preventing access to wp-login.php](https://wordpress.org/support/article/brute-force-attacks/#deny-access-to-no-referrer-requests) for anyone who's not submitting it the form. In my eyes this should get rid of any scripts which try to brute force their way in like:

```
www.mydomain.tld/wp-admin.php?log=admin&pwd=alex
```

Now for anyone submitting the form this wouldn't work, so I added a part to the top of `wp-login.php` which would check for the host name and then re-direct if it doesn't match our ISP:

```
<?PHP
if (strpos(gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),'my.isp.tld') == false) {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
}
?>
```

I checked it and this piece is working fine as well, when I try to access `wp-login.php` over my mobile it throws me back to Google, additionally I get an e-mail when somebody tries this. So far it's only been 3-4 login attempts I prevented using this method.

Now from my perspective I've taken care of all things, but Wordfence will still send me notifications about blocked log-in attempts.

To see if it helps, I've added the following to the [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) file which is in the main Wordpress folder, which, to my understanding, should deny all access except when coming from my ISP:

```
<Files "wp-login.php">
    order deny,allow
    allow from my.isp.tld
</Files>
```

Still the e-mails come flying in. Now the question is:

Is there any other way to call `wp-login.php` in order to try to login which I haven't tought of? It seems that there are still ways which can be used which are not part of the scenarios mentioned above.

As commented in the other question: The IPs with the failed attempts are not spoofed to fit mine.

Any ideas, comments etc. are greatly appreciated.

So long

Comment: This [question here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/204485/26350) was asked recently and might be related.

Comment: Hi @birgire, thanks for this. I will definately try this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question about other login possibilities was given in [the question posted by birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204485/brute-force-attack-even-though-it-is-limited-by-ip).

It turns out that after disabling any remote access to `xmlrpc.php` the attacks went down to zero.

However this might have [serious consequences](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disabling-xml-rpc-may-damage-jetpack) on your website since it's used by e.g. [jetpack](/questions/tagged/jetpack) amongst others and I therefor not recommend it.

As mentioned by Mark Kaplun there are probably other, more serious attacks out there and from analyzing my logs these brute force attacks I've encountered are very basic and wouldn't stand a chance when you did the following:

- Change the admin user name to anything else than "admin"
- Use proper passwords

Answer (score 1):

wrote something long and decided to delete because the Tl;Dr is use a good password and stop pretending to have a knowledge in how to secure sites, you are more likely to bring down the performance of the site (your reverse DNS code) or lock yourself out then actually preventing an attack.

Security is about context, and in the context of wordpress brute force attack is probably the least of your worries, it would not have prevented you to be hacked via 
http://wptavern.com/wordpress-security-alert-new-zero-day-vulnerability-discovered-in-timthumb-script

or http://wptavern.com/critical-security-vulnerability-found-in-wordpress-slider-revolution-plugin-immediate-update-advised

or https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/10/security-advisory-stored-xss-in-jetpack.html

And before even getting to plugins maybe I should have asked is your hosting secure? (can't find the link and don't remember which big hosting company was hacked)

Comment: Still getting used to this sorry (Enter submits, no edits after 5 minutes).No  I don't pretend that I have the knowledge, I simply try to minimize the attack possibilities. From what I know the provider (www.df.eu) has not been compromised. I'll give your links a read later on, thanks for sharing. I'm not worried about locking myself out, since I still got server access. I'll have a look at the solution from @birgire which hopefully will help as well and would make the PHP bit unnecessary.

Comment: Well, you are asking for security advice in a forum which is not dedicated to security with no self proclaimed security experts. What I am trying to say is that if you think that you need better security then strong password then you need to ask a pro and nod get an opinion from half ignorant people (me included), security wise, based  on group think. Strong passwords worked for me since day 1 on the internet with many sites that I admined so this is my expert experience, if you keep the bugs away from your site you don't need more then a good password.

Comment: I see your point and totally agree with the passwords, I do the same. Is there any mailing list which covers security alerts for WP / WP Plugins?